# Unable to install Recharts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, recharts

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/recharts failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:8de3:80e2:e4de:a38:6810:1023:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

I have tried to these commands (npm install recharts --force or npm install recharts --legacy-peer-deps)
Why this is happening. I have no bad network connection.